# Add ViewControllers to Stack and Pop back When required

Tags: ios, push-notification

I want to navigate to specific Class when Click on Notification in Notification bar and after that in that particular class if I click back button I need to Navigate to previous according to requirement.

Can anyone please help.

I have added ViewController to Stack this way

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

    SplashViewController *splashViewCon = (SplashViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SplashId"];
    AgreeViewController *agreeViewCon = (AgreeViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"agreeView"];
    ViewController *loginViewCon = (ViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"loginView"];
    LanguageViewController *languageViewCon = (LanguageViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"languageView"];
    LandingScreenViewController *landingViewCon = (LandingScreenViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"landingScreenId"];
    HomeScreenViewController *homeViewCon = (HomeScreenViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"homeScreen"];
    OrderConfirmationViewController *orderconfirmViewCon = (OrderConfirmationViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"orderConfirmationVC"];
    ThankYouViewController *thankViewCon = (ThankYouViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ThankyouId"];
    UploadQueueScreenViewController *uploadViewCon = (UploadQueueScreenViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"uploadQueue"];
    NewOrderViewController *newOrderViewCon = (NewOrderViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"neworderView"];
    MessageViewController *msgViewCon = (MessageViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MessageInboxscreen"];
    MessageDetailsViewController *msgdetailsViewCon = (MessageDetailsViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"msgDetailsView"];

    NSArray *stack = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:splashViewCon,agreeViewCon,loginViewCon,languageViewCon,landingViewCon,homeViewCon,orderconfirmViewCon,thankViewCon,uploadViewCon,newOrderViewCon,msgViewCon,msgdetailsViewCon, nil];
    navController.viewControllers = stack;

    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (notification)
    {
        MessageDetailsViewController *msgdetailsViewCon = (MessageDetailsViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"msgDetailsView"];
        self.window.rootViewController = msgdetailsViewCon;
    }
}
```

So ,I want pop back to specific viewController

Comment: what is **Notification bar** here?

Comment: yes,its notification bar

Comment: Please provide [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no generic class avaialbe. Try using the NSMutableArray, add via addObject and get first/last via objectAtIndex and removeObjectAtIndex.

You might wan to implement your own code to use those as a Stack.
Cheers :)

Comment: Can u provide code for adding Controllers to navigation stack

Answer (score 2):

Find your viewcontroller in stack and pop it. This code may be help you find it.

```
for (YourViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
        {
            if ([controller isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]])
            {
                [self.navigationController popViewController:controller animated:YES];
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I want to know how to add ViewControllers to stack

Comment: Can anyone pls help me